# How to create external connection with local database in test project?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, specflow, dbcontext

I have in Visual Studio two projects: My normal project and my test-project. I have chosen to use SpecFlow for testing and therefore my tests are UI based. So a database connection is not needed for the UI validation.

In some cases I have to set some preconditions to the system, like filling some sample data in the project. I've tried to connect my project-database to my test-project, but it just won't work. I tried to add connectionstrings to my test-project app.config like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyConnectionString"
  connectionString="Data Source=C:\Users\Martijn\Documents\VS11\Projects\Gastouderuren.nl\testprojectl\App_Data\example.sdf"
  providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I use this connection string in the code as follows:

```
        MyContext context = new MyContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        context.Product.Count();
```

When I run my test, the following error occurs:

```
The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. -> This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection. -> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

I've searched already for a solution, but couldn't find anything. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the connection string in your not-test app?

Answer (score 0):

You **cant** connect to a **external** localdb *(file based)* like the same way you used to connect to normal SQL database
*(connect string)*

its because of localdb limits (No more than 1 apps can connect at once)

**but i have a soulution :** (How to use 2+ applications with 1 localdb)

- You have to create a TCP server listener (In pc where LOCALDB is) and
  X clients where your other pc(s) are
- client pc(s) connect to server pc
- So everytime you want to execute a sql command you send command from
  **CLIENT** to **SERVER** and Server executes it ! (Can send back response to)

you can set some pre definded commands too(i did same thing)

```
SERVER :
if(CLIENT DATA . equals("ReadProducts"){
sql.execute("SELECT * FROM Products");
//convert...
SendBack(result);
}


CLIENT 1 >SEND> SERVER : "ReadProducts" (Predefinded command)

SERVER >SEND> CLIENT 1 : "Apple,Melon,Orange"

CLIENT 1 :

 data = SERVER RESPONSE;

 string[] sp=data.split(',');

//add a for loop which add all products to your listview
CLIENT 2 >SEND> SERVER : "INSERT INTO Products(name) VALUES(@name)"


SERVER :
if(CLIENT DATA . contains("INSERT"){
sql.execute(CLIENT DATA);
}
```

Using algorithm abow you can handle many connections to a single LocalDb file

from another computers but you have to deal with IP problem

get a Static Ip address for server app if you developing something big